# AngularJS UI Router shows blank page with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to split my application to views and starting out with Angular UI Router. I'm creating multiple views and if I use 'template', it prints fine, but when I use templateUrl with an external .html-file, I only get a blank page.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.0/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<script src="searchApp.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="searchApp">
<div ui-view>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**searchApp.js:**

```
var searchApp = angular.module('searchApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    url: "/",
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'testView.html'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}])
```

**testView.html**

```
This is a test.
```

Here's a Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/4xQaHbx71mUNYRbTQntz

**EDIT:**
This seems to work in Plunker, but doesn't work locally on my computer. Tried both on mac and win.

**EDIT 2:**
All I can make of it is that UI Router templateUrl parameter doesn't work when ran straight from the File system but maybe needs a server to be able to open files? Is this so? Any way around it?

**EDIT 3:**
SOLUTION: Seems that the page needs to be run through a server and not straight from file system when using templateUrl (or including any files in general) since they are fetched via Ajax. So - to use templateUrl, you must install a server on your local machine or continue coding on a server instead.

Comment: A server **must** be used with ui-router, since the template pages are fetched via ajax.

Comment: This explains it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had nothing to do with UI-router, since an error was thrown that `angular` could not be found. You were using the wrong URL for loading Angular. Changing

`"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/...`

to

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/...`

made things work.

https://plnkr.co/edit/rSbD4FBIFsnamiaMQLve?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, I can see that it works in the Plunker now, but this still doesn't work locally on my computer. I've tested on both mac and win and copied the code directly from the Plunker. I've been trying to find some reason to this for the whole day... also, angular by itself works, it's just that the ui router templateUrl doesn't work, as described in the original post.

Comment: Perhaps a path misconfiguration?

Comment: Ah, yes... true, that sound like something that could cause this. But how... what configuration does ui router need than the one given in the state-methods?

Comment: As an addition to previous post - I'm running these straight by clicking the index.html on mac finder and windows file explorer so no additional server setups.

Comment: You do need a server to run this, the templates are fetched via ajax calls

Comment: Being new here, it was the comments that solved it, should I mark the original answer accepted in that case or can I somehow accept the comments? EDIT: did it already. :)